# How to select element within a div using DOM?

Tags: javascript, arrays, visual-studio, dom

I'm learning DOM and I'm trying to select an li within a div, where the div has an ID of 'essentials'
I want to target all li within that div and change the background color. I was able to change the background color of the div itself, but can't seem to select just the li. Here's my code:

HTML

```
    <ul>
      <li>milk</li>
      <li class="selected">honey</li>
      <li>water</li>
      <li>wine</li>
      <li>beer</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('essentials').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers provide you with two fantastic APIs for targeting DOM elements:

`document.querySelector` (get one element) and `document.querySelectorAll` (get more than one element)

These two methods allow you to target DOM elements using CSS selectors. For example:

With the following HTML:

```html
<div id="essentials">
  <ul>
    <li>milk</li>
    <li class="selected">honey</li>
    <li>water</li>
    <li>wine</li>
    <li>beer</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can target the `li` tags you want with this JavaScript:

```js
var myLiTags = document.querySelectorAll('#essentials li'):
```

Now, to style your targeted `li` tags, you can do this:

```js
myLiTags.forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
});
```

Of course, if you don't need to do this with JavaScript, styling elements is what CSS was made for:

```html
<style>
  #essentials li {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

Putting this code in your HTML document will work as well as the JavaScript code above, but is actually the best-practices way of styling DOM elements.

---

If you're new to CSS Selectors, [here's a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)

Comment: Actually I've already gone through HTML, CSS, and JS courses. We are now learning DOM and this is the way we have to do it. I understand that this can easily be accomplished through CSS. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll

```js
    var q = document.querySelectorAll('#essentials li');
    console.log('q' + q.length);
    q.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    });
```

```html
<body>
<div id="essentials">
<ul>
<li>a
<li>b
<li>c
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This code didn't work.

Comment: @KevMcCall you can run the code snippet and see that it does